# Compute parity matrix in $GF(3)$

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, coding-theory

I want to compute the control matrix/parity matrix $H$, when given a generating matrix $G$ for a linear code in $GF(3)$:

G = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I am aware that the matrices have the following structure:

$G = [I|P]$

$H = [-P^T|I]$

My questions are the following:

1. Do I have to bring $G$ in canonical form first, aka have the identity matrix on the left? Because currently, I and P are basically on the wrong sides.
2. I know that when transposing $P$ to $-P^T$ in $GF(2)$ the values are essentially unchanged, aka $-0$ is still $0$ and $-1$ is $1$. But how is this in $GF(3)$? What is $-0$,$-1$ and $-2$? They are different, right?

Comment: Anyone got an idea?

Comment: $x+(-x)=0$ in any field. So in $GF(3)$ we have $-1=$____?

Comment: So I suppose its just $1$? So, I can essentially just ignore the minus for the transposed values in any $\mathbb{F}_q = \{0, 1, 2, ..., q-1\}$? And what about the first part, the mirroring of the values?

Comment: Wrong. $-1=1$ if and only if $1+1=0$. What I was saying is that $-1$ is the solution $x$ to $1+x=0$. But the check matrix you can find using that same recipe. $H$ is a generator matrix for the dual code, and $G$ is its check matrix, so their forms can be intechanged. It is immaterial whether the identity block is on the left or on the right.